# Can we hide 1/2 columns while displaying wxtreelistctrl?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am using wxtreelistctrl to construct a tree and I want to store 4 columns in it, but while displaying I want to display only 2 columns. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

With `wxTreeListCtrl` this is not directly supported, but you could set column width to 0 as a quick and dirty hack.

With `wxDataViewCtrl` itself, you can perfectly well show just some of the columns of your `wxDataViewModel` in the GUI control.

Comment: Also I have 1 more doubt:  I am building treelist project from samples of wxWidgets 3.0.3. After running that treelist project, I got a window, I selected "2-state-checkboxes" and "multiple selections" from style. then I selected some of the checkboxes of that tree. when I clicked on "Dumpselections" from operations. Now, while debugging controller is going into OnDumpSelection(). but I am not able to see proper value of "numSelected". And it is not even executing for loop from default case properly. Is it a bug or I am doing some mistake?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean, this probably merits a new question.

Comment: Yes, I posted a new question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986516/getselections-is-not-working-properly-for-wxtreelistctrl-sample-from-wxwidgets