# Getselections() is not working properly for wxtreelistctrl sample from wxWidgets 3.0.3

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am building `treelist` project from `samples` folder of `wxWidgets 3.0.3`. After running that treelist project, I got a window, I selected `2-state-checkboxes` and `multiple selections` from style. then I selected some of the checkboxes of that tree. when I clicked on `Dumpselections` from `operations`. Now, while debugging controller is going into `OnDumpSelection()`. In `Ondumpselection()`, `getselections()` is executed, here `getselections` should return total no of selected nodes and go into default case of switch case. Then it should execute for loop to display every  selected node. But, while debugging I am not able to see proper value of `numSelected`. Also,  for loop from default case is not executing properly. Is it a bug or I am doing some mistake?

```
void MyFrame::OnItemChecked(wxTreeListEvent& event)
{
    wxTreeListItem item = event.GetItem();
    wxCheckBoxState itemCheckboxState =m_treelist->GetCheckedState(item);
    m_treelist->CheckItemRecursively(item, itemCheckboxState);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Selection refers to the items being selected, and not checkboxes being checked as you seem to assume. There is no function like `GetSelections()` for getting all the items in the checked state because this is not often useful in practice: typically you would look at the top level item, test if it is checked, then look at its children and so on.

But you can, of course, write a `GetCheckedItems()` function if you need one, you just will have to use `GetRootItem()` and `GetFirstChild()` and `GetNextSibling()` recursively.

Comment: In GetCheckedItems() function I am thinking to use BFS instead of recursive calls, or instead of writing GetCheckedItems() funtion, can I generate "EVT_TREELIST_SELECTION_CHANGED" event everytime when any item is checked or unchecked? I mean when any item is checked, that item and its all children(child subtree) will get selected. when an item is unchecked, that item and its children will be unselected. so when I call GetSelections() function I will get all selected nodes. Is it possible? which method will take less memory and time?

Comment: If you want to select some items, just call `Select()`, no need to generate about any events. Also, if you have nearly sufficiently many items to worry about performance, forget about `wxTreeListCtrl` and use `wxDataViewCtrl` directly.

Comment: `wxDataViewCtrl` doesn't have `wxTL_CHECKBOX` so I am using `wxTreeListCtrl`. I need checkboxes for every node. and finally retrieve items whose checkboxes are marked checked. I am using `GetFirstChild()` and `GetNextSibling()` as you said for BFS. Is there anything that I can do for reducing its time and memory, any suggestions?

Comment: Again, if you have many (e.g. several thousands or more) items, you must use `wxDataViewCtrl`, `wxTreeListCtrl` is not designed for this case, it is designed for simplicity first and foremost. So yes, using `wxDVC` will be more involved than just setting `wxTL_CHECKBOX` flag, but it's still not that difficult and you can look at `wxTreeListCtrl` code itself to see how it does it (because it uses `wxDVC` internally).

Comment: I am not getting exactly what you are saying. I need to display a Tree structure with 1 checkboxe for every node . I need to select/unselect checkboxes recursively when any parent checkbox state is changed, In the end I need to retrieve all nodes whose checkbox is marked checked after we click OK Button. You are saying that I need to add wxTL_CHECKBOX code in wxDateViewCtrl? If yes then can u guide me in this?

Comment: What you want to do can be done either with `wxTreeListCtrl` or `wxDataViewCtrl`. It's much simpler to do it with the former, however it's not a good idea if you have many items. I have no idea how many of them you have, what you need to do depends on the answer to this question.

Comment: I will have around 1-10 lac records/nodes, maybe more than that also.

Comment: If "lac" is 100,000, so that you can have up to 1e6 lines, then you definitely can't use `wxTreeListCtrl` and need to define a custom `wxDataViewModel` (because you presumably don't want to store all this data in memory or at least not duplicate it).

Comment: Yes, for defining custom DataViewModel, First I need to create a wxTL_CHECKBOX and when this flag is set I have to display checlboxes for each node. Can you please help me how can I achieve this? Also I need to create oncheck, onrecursivelychecked events also.

Comment: When you use `wxDataViewCtrl`, you don't use `wxTreeListCtrl` any more, so `wxTL_CHECKBOX` is completely irrelevant. Again, the example showing how to do this is, in fact, `wxTreeListCtrl` itself -- look at its implementation.

Comment: Yes, I shall look at wxTreeListCtrl's implementation